# How to retrieve ref from hoc translated component by i18next

Tags: javascript, reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I use i18next to translate my components in separate repo. Now I need to use method from one component in my main project.
This is example component:

```
class ExampleComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      text: '',
    };
    this.resetText = this.resetText.bind(this);
  }

  resetText() {
    this.setState({
    text: '',
    });
  }

  render() {
    <div/>
  }

export default translate('components', { withRef: true })(ExampleComponent);
```

And now I need to use resetText in my main project, without translations it works fine

```
class MainComponent extends Component {

  resetComponent() {
    return () => this.exampleComponent.resetText();
  }

  renderExampleComponent() {
    return (
      <ExampleComponent
        ref={(exampleComponent) => { this.exampleComponent = exampleComponent; }}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.resetComponent()}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I tried this.refs.exampleComponent.resetText(); but it not works.
In i18next documentation I found "withRef | store a ref to the wrapped component and access it by decoratedComponent.getWrappedInstance();" but where should I use this getWrappedInstance() to make it works? 
Someone have experience with this?

Greetings

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think with the provided code, your ref returns a wrapper, so you need to call getWrappedInstance on it: `this.refs.exampleComponent.getWrappedInstance().resetText();`

Comment: So simple.. I tried this.exampleComponent = exampleComponent.getWrappedInstance() and this didn't worked so I didn't think about this.refs.exampleComponent.getWrappedInstance().resetText(); Thanks!